# What is the value of the following expressions?

Tags: c++, boolean-logic

My C++ programming professor gave the students some exercises about boolean algebra.

Two of them were:
1) true || true
2) true && false

The possible answers for the two are the following:
a) true
b) false
c) 1
d) -1

What is the correct way to evaluate these exercises, and possibly, other exercises of the same type?

Comment: `True || True` isn't valid code AFAIK, because boolean literals need to be lowercase.  The value `+1` may be treated as true in certain situations.

Comment: What is `True`? That's not a valid C++ identifier.

Comment: What exactly is `True` here? Is it an object? If you meant the boolean value, it must be `true` in small case.

Comment: My C++ professor asked me this question, just like that.  The possible answers were 1, -1, True, or False.

Comment: I think he refers to some kind of boolean algebra, but he was not very clear about it.

Comment: I just modifed the question. Is it more clear now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`True` is not a valid keyword in C++. But `true` & `false` are keywords in C++.

Boolean variables are variables that can have only two possible values: true (1), and false (0). so `true || true` will evaluate to 1. 
See live demo [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/055236721cea7c72).

Comment: Isn't `bool` a proper type in C++, just like `int`?  `true` is not the same as `1`, but if you do `true == 1`, the `true` will be casted to `int`, which gives `1`.  So `true || true` will not evaluate to `1`.  It will evaluate to the boolean value `true`.  The demo works because C++ streams by default have their [`boolalpha`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/boolalpha/) flag unset, meaning that writing `true` to a stream will result in `"1"` and not `"true"`.

Comment: Actually, your link mentions `boolalpha`, and doesn't say anywhere that `true || true` will evaluate to `1`, or even that `true` by itself will evaluate to `1`, for that matter.  The link does not support your answer.